# The moduli space of finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds

By finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifold, I do mean $M=\mathbb{H}^{3}/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a torsion-free Kleinian group such that the hyperbolic volume $Vol(M)<\infty$.

I will call
$$\mathcal{M}:=\{\textrm{finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifolds}\}/_{\cong_ {isometry}} $$

The moludi space of finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifolds.
As far as I understand, the hyperbolic volume function $$Vol: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$$ has some nice properties: the image of this function is closed and well-ordered subset of $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and the preimage $Vol(x)^{-1}$ is finite for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

I have no knowledge in this field, but out of curiosity I wanted to know if there is some research done in understanding $\mathcal{M}$, is there a natural topological structure on it? is $\mathcal{M}$ an manifold or an orbifold ? Can we endow $\mathcal{M}$ with some algebraic or geometrical structure ?

Comment: The rigidity of hyperbolic 3-manifolds means that the only natural topology on $\mathcal M$ is zero-dimensional. With the discrete topology, it is a manifold in the trivial sense of a set with the discrete topology. There may also be a natural topology which is still totally disconnected but not discrete.

Comment: Indeed, a nontrivial topology is given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_topology_(object) It is still totally disconnected, and thus can't really be said to be a geometric (or algebraic) structure

Comment: @WillSawin the link looks very interesting! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By Mostow rigidity theorem two hyperbolic manifolds are isometric if they have the same fundamental group, so there are really no deformations and, thus, manifold structure.

Comment: But how about some algebraic or geometric structure on $\mathcal{M}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the [geometric topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_topology_(object)): that is, the topology of Gromov-Hausdorff convergence.  This is closely related to Thurston's [hyperbolic Dehn surgery theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_Dehn_surgery).

There are further approaches to producing a "space" of three-manifolds.  In [this video](https://youtu.be/suHprWZUjYk?t=2040) Thurston alludes to cone-manifold deformations and commensurability relations.  I vaguely remember that he also had a kind of "solenoid" space that contained all hyperbolic three manifolds (finite and infinite volume) as leaves.  I can't find references to this on-line - perhaps another reader will help us.

Comment: The "solenoid space" you refer to is probably related to the space of pointed hyperbolic manifolds (with pointed Hausdorff topology) where each single hyperbolic manifold gives a "leaf" in there via the map $M \ni x \mapsto (M, x)$.

Comment: cone-manifold deformations give a geometric interpretation for the deformation space of a cusped manifold, which is a manifold "filling in" the space between the manifolds obtained by Dehn filling the cusps (which is a 0-dimensional subset). A good reference on this deformation space (besides Thurston's original notes) is the paper of Neumann and Zagier (https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0589.57015)

Comment: @JeanRaimbault - Is there are reference for this?  And in particular some discussion of Thurston's?  I definitely remember this coming up in talks (in the 90's and 00's) but I could not find anything online.

Comment: regarding the space of 3--manifolds you can find some explanations, together with examples of solenoidal subspaces (minimal laminations with transverse space a Cantor) in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09510.pdf ; I'm not aware of earlier references on this specific topic though this was certainly well-known.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.